# Trying to Solve LeetCode power of 4 using recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

Given an integer `n`, return `true` if it is a power of four. Otherwise, return `false`.

An integer `n` is a power of four, if there exists an integer `x` such that `n == 4ˣ`.

```
class Solution(object):
    def isPowerOfFour(self, n, count = 1):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if n == 4:
            return True
        if n > 4:
            return self.isPowerOfFour(pow(n,1/count),count + 1)
```

I keep getting False as an output

Comment: `if there exists an integer x such that n == 4x` — are you sure that's correct?

Comment: Yeah, it should be `4ˣ`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I pass an input that's less than `4`, e.g. `2`, your function will return `None`. I'm not sure why you say that the function returns `False`, but I think that might just be some quirk in LeetCode's testing infrastructure.

Anyway, to solve this problem using recursion, we make three observations:

1. `1` is a power of 4.
2. For `n > 1`, if  `n` can be expressed as `4^x` for some integer `x`, then so can `n // 4` (as it would be equivalent to `4^(x - 1)`).
3. If a number isn't divisible by 4 and is greater than 1, it isn't a power of 4.

This gives us the following recursive solution:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def isPowerOfFour(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if n == 1:
            return True
        elif n % 4 != 0:
            return False
        return self.isPowerOfFour(n // 4)
```

Comment: Dude, thanks for the explanation !

Comment: @Pmesh, it seems this answer suited your needs. In that case consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**Power of Four solution in c# by recursion:**

```
public bool IsPowerOfFour(int n)  {

    if (n <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (n % 4 == 0)
    {
        return IsPowerOfFour(n / 4);
    }
    return false;
}
```